# How to find all properties that i can use in the properties file in intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Like the title says, is there any source where I can find all properties that I can use in
properties file or is there at least auto-completion in properties file so when I type it pops out.
I'm using Intellij and I'm developing spring Project.

Comment: Please clarify the problem with the sample project and the specific file where the completion doesn't work for you. [It works fine for me](https://i.imgur.com/yoiAnLT.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder well it doesn't for me, what edition do you have Ultimate or community?,
mine is the latter, I will continue to search for a solution for this problem because
auto-completion is essential for me really -_-

Comment: The screenshot is from IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.3.1. Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Are you talking about application.properties (i.e. configuration for Spring Boot)? Or do you mean other types of properties files (e.g. messages.properties for translations of texts)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder what i think the problem is, is because the Community edition doesn't have Sprint boot built-in but i tried showing suggestion(Ctrl + space) with java or javax
and same massage "no suggestion" image -> https://i.imgur.com/wacxe7v.png

Comment: @dunni  application.properties i think because it's Community edition, can anyone confirm that??
i'm just assuming.

Comment: @StreamsGit See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html. Community Edition has no support for Spring specific features and completion.

Answer (score 2):

A compilation of all common application properties are available as part of the official documentation.: [Common Application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)

Comment: @StreamsGit Glad to help. You may upvote if this answer helped and can also mark this as the answer . Please read through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I wish I could buddy in fact I tried but it says that I must have 15 reputation and I only have 11 -_

Comment: Well you can now, including accepting the answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Support for Spring and Spring Boot functionalities such as views showing Spring beans in the application, completion support for properties etc. is only part of IntelliJ Ultimate, but not Community edition (note, that you can still develop applications based on Spring or Spring Boot, this only applies to supplemental features in the IDE).